# make a movie clip come back up after going down to a certain depth automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

hi please have a look at the code. When I press keyboard the object goes down however what I want is that when it reached a certain depth it should come back..any help would be appreciated , thank you

```
//rope coding
var rope = MovieClip(this.root).boat_mc.rope_mc;
var ropeMove:Boolean = false;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ropeCode);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onSpacebarUp);

    function onSpacebarUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
            ropeMove = !ropeMove; // toggles ropeMove (i.e. if it's true, sets it to false, and vice versa)
    }

    function ropeCode(e:Event):void
    {
        //check direction of rope
        if(yDirection) 
        {
          rope.y += ropeSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
          rope.y -= ropeSpeed;
        }


        // move the rope
        if( ropeMove )
        {
            if( rope.y < 230) 
            {
                yDirection = true;
                trace(rope.y);
            }
            // stop moving if we've gone too far
            else if (rope.y > 230) 
            {
                yDirection = false;
            }
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 checks  like

```
if( rope.y < 230)
```

and

```
if( rope.y > 230)
```

I think your animation  could get stuck when y is 230 
so make one of those to test for equality  like

```
if( rope.y < =230)
```

or add a third case

```
else if(y==230)
```

Edit:
add a new variable/field named yDirection

```
var yDirection:Boolean=true;
```

when you want to change the direction flip this flag

```
if( rope.y <=0)
  yDirection=true;
else 
  yDirection=false;

if(yDirection)
  rope.y=+=speed;
else
  rope.y-=speed;
```

EDIT2
Hi had a bug in previous edit, replace the rope.y <=0 with the value you need (minY value)

EDIT3
The solutions is easy, you must check the ropeMove value,

```
if(ropeMove){

    if( rope.y <=0)
      yDirection=true;
    else 
      yDirection=false;

    if(yDirection)
      rope.y=+=speed;
    else
      rope.y-=speed;
}
```

Your questions are very basic so you should learn the basics of algorithms,

Comment: no unfortunately what happens is that it starts going back as soon as it jumps reaches the depth but then instantly goes back down and goes into a loop

Comment: now the movieclip just starts dropping by itself and keeps on going ..no reverse nothing  it doesnt even wait for spacebar to be clicked lol, please check the new code above

Comment: see the problem is when i declare the boolean value its either true or false and as such ..it automatically either starts going up or down.

Comment: thanks it works and yes you are right i need to improve my coding.